# Как заменить символы в строке кроме первого?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу приложение - игру "Угадай слово" на windowsforms.

Из текстового файла случайно выбирается слово word.

Данный метод скрывает все буквы этого слова и вместо них показывает знак "_"(писал не сам, скопировал).

```
public  void MakeLabels()
{
    word =  GetRandomWord();
    char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
    int between = 330 / chars.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        labels.Add(new Label());
        labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
        labels[i].Text = "_";
        labels[i].Parent = groupBox1;
        labels[i].BringToFront();
        labels[i].CreateControl();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы скрывались все буквы кроме первой.

Например, если слово "СПОРТ" то показывалось "C _ _ _ _".

Answer (score 4):

Закину альтернативные варианты, раз очевидные варианты перечислили.

Можно через LINQ:

```
static string NewWord(string src)
    {
        return src[0] + new string(src.Skip(1).Select(x => '_').ToArray());
    }
```

Можно регулярочкой:

```
   static string NewWord(string src)
    {
        return src[0] + Regex.Replace(src.Substring(1), ".", "_");
    }
```

Comment: Раз уж вы пошли по пути разделения на отдельные функции, то я бы сразу добавил параметр для заполнителя со значением по умолчанию "_" - чтобы потом два раза не вставать, когда придётся менять на другой символ, скажем на "X". А так, пожалуй, самый красивый вариант решения из всех пока  предложеных.

Comment: Если необходимо будет сделать пробел между `_` то Ваш вариант придется переделать, а именно поменять `Select` на `SelectMany`

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
string word = "слово";
string encryptWord = word[0] + (new string('_', word.Length - 1));
```

Первая буква остается, остальные буквы "заменяются" на `_`

**UPD**
    Если необходимо сделать пробелы между первой буквой и знаками `_`

```
private string HideCharacters(string word)
{
    string res = word[0].ToString();
    for (int i = 1; i < word.Length; i++)
        res += " _";
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Данный в вопросе метод я изменил следующим образом:

```
 public void MakeLabels()
   {    word = GetRandomWord();
        char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
        int between = 330 / chars.Length;
        labels.Add(new Label());
        labels[0].Location = new Point((0* between) + 10, 80);
        labels[0].Text = chars[0].ToString();
        labels[0].Parent = groupBox1;
        labels[0].BringToFront();
        labels[0].CreateControl();
       for (int i = 1; i < chars.Length; i++) 
        {
            labels.Add(new Label());
            labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
            labels[i].Text = "_";
            labels[i].Parent = groupBox1;
            labels[i].BringToFront();
            labels[i].CreateControl();
        }
    }
```

Вследствие чего, изначально на экране показывается первая буква слова, а остальные заменяются символом "_"

Comment: А вас не беспокоит код, который повторяется 2 раза подряд ? А если ошибка??? Поменяете в одном месте, а про второе забудете...

Answer (score 0):

Допиши: `if(i != 0)`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    labels.Add(new Label());
    labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
    if(i!=0)labels[i].Text = "_";
    labels[i].Parent = groupBox1;
    labels[i].BringToFront();
    labels[i].CreateControl();
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код как код. Выделите фрагмент кода, нажмите Ctrl + K или кнопку `{}` на панели.

Comment: Условия if красивее выглядят с переносом строки, у вас всё слеплено до нечитаемости. И ведь буква не будет показываться совсем, допишите ветку условия.

Comment: в вашем случае первая буква вообще не показывается,

Comment: @AltynbekTanbayev: Ну так впишите на место `_` первую букву в этом случае.

Comment: @VladD Вряд ли он сможет, судя по тому что код полностью скопирован и нет понимания как поправить. Так что только ждать, пока кто-то сжалится и поможет.

Comment: `if(i!=0)labels[i].Text = "_";` не является верным, т.к. не учитывает первую букву вообще